# Run an activity on application start to fetch data from the internet

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to get a Thread running on the background when I start my application.

The main focus here is that the new thread is going to fetch data from a PHP page that I have and save it to a list and afterwards save that to a XML file which I can access from everywhere on the application.

I have a new Activity with the code already prepared, but if I use a normal Thread like this:

```
new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(FetchData));
        })).Start();
```

it won't work as intended to. I'm running this code on the MainActivity and it starts the activity and the application doesn't show me the MainActivity layout until I press back on the phone.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using a Service to do the job instead

Comment: I've tried to use that now and no sucess so far. Can you provide me a basic Service class with the necessary methods where I can call my code to run on the background and the proper code to call the service on the MainActivity? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity (a bit confusing name for anyone new to android) - is part of the UI. It is similar to Form (.NET forms app) or Page (ASP.NET). If you dont want any UI but rather a background task, you dont need another activity. If your job is somehow periodic, you can use Service: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/

Otherwise just run in once in the background - you have multiple options here: Task.Run() is probably the best. In your existing activity, in OnResume() method do something like this:

```
Task.Run(() => {
  return FetchData();
}).ContinueWith(task => {
  // process the result of FetchData here.
  // this can be another thread, so watch out, if you want to modify UI, 
  // you must do it in RunOnUiThread()
});
```

Comment: It says "The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context", and I can't get it. Never worked with these 'Tasks' before, can I have some deeper help? Anyway, thank you for the quick resume above, now I got the difference between the service and the activity :) !

Comment: Uh oh.. Task is part of the Task Parallel Library (TPL), new awesome way to help programmers write simple and maintanable parallel code. It is not the easiest thing to learn, but very well worth every minute, trust me. Here is very light intro: http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks

Comment: Yeah but it was my mistake. I didn't put the namespace on the top, so that's why it didn't exist. I will read that later, now I wanna know if the thread did what was supposed to, how can I do that?